# AngularJS posting empty to database

Tags: php, angularjs, database

First of all forgive my bad English. 
So when making this code I bumped into an error.

My code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="todo" ng-controller="listController">
    <div class="item">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add an item</legend>
                <label for="item-name">Item Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="item-name" ng-model="itemName" id="item-name">

                <label for="item-deadline">Item Deadline</label>
                <input type="text" name="item-deadline" ng-model="itemDeadline" id="item-deadline">

                <label for="item-description">Item Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="item-description" ng-model="itemDescription" id="item-description">

                <label></label>
                <input type="submit" ng-click="itemInsert()">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('todo', []);
app.controller('listController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.itemInsert = function () {
        $http.post("pages/insert.php", {'itemName': $scope.itemName, 'itemDeadline': $scope.itemDeadline, 'itemDescription': $scope.itemDescription})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log('Success');
        });
    };
});
```

insert.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->itemName);
$itemDeadline = mysql_real_escape_string($data->itemDeadline);
$itemDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($data->itemDescription);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("todo") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `items`(`name`, `deadline`, `description`) VALUES ('" . $itemName . "', '" . $itemDeadline . "', '" . $itemDescription . "')");
Print "Success";
```

When inserting into the database it's just inserting empty rows. 
I can't find the error myself but I guess it has something to do with:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: Is the form data present in the network request?

Comment: @hughes this is what it shows in the network http://prntscr.com/8ujjgq

Comment: I see you found your own answer, but I was suggesting you check the form data in the request to `insert.php`. If you click the request in the network tab, you'll see a "Request Body" section. If you see the expected data in there, you can narrow down the problem to the client side (if the data is not present) or the server side (if the data is present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kinda found the answer...

I had to put the connection above the mysql_real_escape_string.

Result:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("todo") or die(mysql_error());

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->itemName);
$itemDeadline = mysql_real_escape_string($data->itemDeadline);
$itemDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($data->itemDescription);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `items`(`name`, `deadline`, `description`) VALUES ('" . $itemName . "', '" . $itemDeadline . "', '" . $itemDescription . "')");
Print "Success";
```

Yes I'm aware I should use PDO or mysqli but was just testing some angular.